# Can rsync command run using multiple cpu?

Tags: rsync, cpu

I executed this command but it took long time when checking checksum.
Load average was 1.00 at all times.
Can rsync command run using multiple cpu?

```
$ rsync --checksum -av -e ssh /usr/local/xxx/* hostname:/usr/local/xxx/
```

cpu: 4 core, OS: CentOS release 5.11, Shell: bash

Comment: To my knowledge, not natively. Take a look at https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/29166227 for an idea on a workaround.

Comment: The bottleneck when using rsync is usually not CPU. It's usually the Network or disk IO

Comment: @JeffSchaller , Thank you for your advice. I'll check the website.

Comment: @DeepakMittal , I see. In my case, I had enormous files. Then it took long time when checking checksum. Thank you.

Comment: `--checksum` will lead to one process being limited by CPU, as that's quite a cpu-intensive operation. Note: `-e ssh` is redundant, that's been the default for many years now.

Comment: @wurtel, thank you for your advice. Hmm, I see, It seems difficult that using multiple CPU. Oh, I didn't need '-e ssh' option, I learned. Thank you for your kindness!